# Interactive marker attached to a moving frame?

Tags: ros, frame, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to ROS and working in C++ and kinetic. I am able to create an interactive marker attached to the "world" frame and set its pose. But if I attach the interactive marker to a moving piece of my robot (defined with a .urdf), the interactive marker does not appear. Is there a simple example of attaching an interactive marker to a moving frame that I can scrutinize? Have been searching for one but I'm coming up empty.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262866/interactive-marker-attached-to-a-moving-frame?/) by [mogumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30569/mogumbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2017-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you. The problem was that I included this line when creating markers:

```
int_marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

This causes interactive markers attached to moving frames to not appear. What's more, adding the stamp to just one marker causes **all** markers to not appear, not just the one that has the stamp. Adding a stamp does not appear to cause any problems for markers in the "world" frame that have their poses updated constantly.

I read some about tf and timestamps, but I still don't understand what's going on here. Can anyone explain it?

---

Originally posted by [mogumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30569/mogumbo/) with karma: 171 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-08**:
I ran into this problem also, and made an issue here: https://github.com/ros-visualization/interactive_markers/issues/34

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2017-06-08**:
If you assign a (valid) timestamp, the marker should appear but not be moving at all, since it will use the transform from that particular moment in time. Might be a bug. See http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/InteractiveMarker.html

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2017-06-08**:
Do you run this on multiple computers, i.e. ros::Time::now() is not from the same clock as the tf info?

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30569/mogumbo/) on 2017-06-08**:
It's the same computer. I'm not going to guess whether or not this is a bug--I haven't been using ROS long enough.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [basic_controls](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Getting%20Started#basic_controls) example in the [interactive_marker_tutorials](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/interactive_marker_tutorials) package has a [moving marker](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/blob/indigo-devel/interactive_marker_tutorials/scripts/basic_controls.py#L394-L416). There is a tf broadcaster that uses a timer to [repeatedly update the transform](https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/blob/indigo-devel/interactive_marker_tutorials/scripts/basic_controls.py#L49-L53) between `base_link` and `moving_frame`. The moving marker uses `moving_frame` as its frame_id, and if you set the `base_link` frame as the fixed frame in rviz, you'll see the moving marker move in a sinusoidal pattern (even though its pose in the `moving_frame` frame is fixed).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2